# Can I use Drupal 7's CSS/JS cache buster/token programmatically?

Tags: 7, caching

By default Drupal adds a cachebuster to CSS and JS resources:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url("http://example.com/modules/system/system.base.css?o0xoqx");
@import url("http://example.com/modules/system/system.menus.css?o0xoqx");
@import url("http://example.com/modules/system/system.messages.css?o0xoqx");
@import url("http://example.com/modules/system/system.theme.css?o0xoqx");
</style>
```

Is there a way to use the cache token (`o0xoqx`) programmatically in the template?

I'd like an easy way to add the same token to some other resources later on (namely: the whole lot of modern favicons), so I could "refresh" them more easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You certainly can, it's just a variable:

```
$current_token = variable_get('css_js_query_string', '0');
```